# how to dynamically resize bootstrap-wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

We are using bootstrap-wysihtml5 to allow the user to enter notes.
I need to allow the user to expand the edit area when they have alot to enter, preferably giving them a full screen option.
(TinyMCE has that built in)

I can't find that option, nor do I know how or where to code it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Going over [the docs](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/#options) I couldn't find any generic resize option.

- You can try [jQuery UI resize](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea).
- There is also [this smaller script](http://www.twinhelix.com/javascript/dragresize/) and with a little tweaking can solve your issue.